# Evaluating the integral $\int_{\partial\Bbb D}\frac{e^z\sin z}{(1-e^z)^2}\, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

I want to evaluate the integral

$$\int_{\partial\Bbb D}\frac{e^z\sin z}{(1-e^z)^2}\, dz$$

where $\partial\Bbb D$ is the boundary of the unit disk. Then its clear that the unique singularity of the integrand is at $z=0$, thus I checked if this singularity is a simple pole evaluating

$$\lim_{z\to 0}z\cdot\frac{e^z\sin z}{(1-e^z)^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac12\cdot\frac{z^2}{\cosh z -1}=1$$

Thus using the residue theorem I found that the value of the integral is $2\pi i$. However checking the answer with [WolframMathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/possible-bug-with-contour-integration) it seems to give a value of zero.

Im not sure if my solution is correct. Can someone confirm it? Thank you.

Comment: Where  is the link to WA's result? Anyway, the residue indeed is $\;1\;$ .

Comment: The link to that notebook is blocked. Anyway, sometimes WA's bugs are annoying.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: @RonGordon I edited to clarify this question.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: $\texttt{Mathematica}$ yields the wrong result $\color{red}{0}$ too. My version is somehow old $\left(\,\texttt{10.0.0.0}\,\right)$.